# Socket/Timeout in Azure WebRole for synchronous communication with WCF Host in WorkerRole

Tags: wcf, azure, net.tcp

I'm trying to get this to work on an internal tcp connection. The code runs flawlessly in development but when deployed to Azure I get ...

a CommunicationException "The socket connection was aborted" trying to connect to "net.tcp://......" with a time code about 60 seconds it waited.

wcf host side:

```
_WCFHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IServiceWCFContract), new NetTcpBinding(),_ServiceUrl);
_WCFHost.Open();
```

wcf client side:

```
var channelfactory = new ChannelFactory<IServiceWCFContract>(new NetTcpBinding(), service.Url);            
channelfactory.Open(new TimeSpan(0,0,20)); //20 sec timeout
var resp = channel.GetValues();
```

I'm sure I'm grabbing the correct url from the RoleEnvironment.Roles["WcfWorkerRole"].Instances

I've made sure enableNativeCodeExecution = "true" is set in the .csdef in both roles.

Ive tried basic http binding too, but azure doesn't like the worker roles having http: names spaces.

Answer (score 0):

on the forum of windows azure there are a lot of [posts](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazure/thread/4d9c1b63-f736-4b97-be0b-8b1dd780ea65) suggesting that a tcp binding is currently not supported. I would try changing the endpoint to wsHttp and checking if that works.